# Encode HTML from JSON response

Tags: android, encoding

I got a json response and have to render **Message** to html in a textView

```
     {
        "CaseNote": 
        [
           {
                "ID": 575732,
                "CaseID": 218320,
                "Date": "6/15/2014 3:04:12 PM",
                "Message": "&lt;table id='tblUpdateHistory' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;td align='left' colspan='3' valign='top'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Case Update History&lt;b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;td class='istColumn' align='left'&gt;&lt;b&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='secondColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Old Value&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='thirdColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Updated Value&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr align='left'&gt;&lt;td class='istColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;Phone&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='secondColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;2034947144&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='thirdColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;203-494-7144&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;",
                "Status": 2,
                "ReOpened": "False",
                "UserName": "Jill Bailey",
                "Source": "CallCenter",
                "OriginalRequest": "False"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And i have tried four ways to encode html but none of them work.

```
  String firstEncoding = TextUtils.htmlEncode(itemList.get(position).getMessage());
  String secondEncoding =  Html.escapeHtml(itemList.get(position).getMessage().toString());

  String firstOne = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(itemList.get(position).getMessage());
  String secondOne = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(itemList.get(position).getMessage());
```

then I try to set it in below method

```
public static void setHtml(TextView textView, String bodyData) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        } else {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData));
        }
    }
```

None of the above method encode my html properly. Which encoding am i doing wrong.

**Half Problem Solved.**

I found my mistake instead of `escapeHtml4` . I have to use `UnescapeHtml4` but still **&nbsp** don't taking space . Now only it is not taking space like below view..

```
Case Update History
    Old Value   Updated Value
Phone   2034947144  203-494-7144
```

Comment: you probably need to *decode* the text first, so `&lt` is replaced with `<`, etc.

Comment: what actually you want to do?

Comment: how does look like your body data? how are you decoding your json? and how you want to shown in textview?

Comment: The only **nbsp;** I can see is misspelled (it misses the **&**). The rest is a layout design issue.

Comment: What you trying to do? Put on differents TextView those data?